# Training a model with single output on multiple losses keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am building an image segmentation model using keras and I want to train my model on multiple loss functions. I have seen [this](https://gaborvecsei.wordpress.com/2018/10/15/implement-loss-functions-inside-keras-models/) link but I am looking for a simpler and straight-forward solutions for this situation as my loss functions are quite complex. Can someone tell me how to build a model with single output with multiple losses in keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple losses with one output using weighted loss, which is a sum of your losses multiplied by weight. Create your custom loss which will return a sum of other losses with coefficients and pass it to `model.compile`. There is an example [here](https://deepakbaby.github.io/post/keras-multiple-losses/).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example from [here](https://keras.io/api/losses/#creating-custom-losses). You could play around with it.

```
def custom_losses(y_true, y_pred):
    alpha = 0.6
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    Huber = tf.keras.losses.huber(y_true, y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1) + (alpha*Huber)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_losses,metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])
```